# Cannot Update Docuement

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose

For some reason, I cannot update a document by id using mongoose and typescript. I am  testing the api and passing in the id as a parameter

I have tried several different methods of updating by ID. I can update by comparing any other fields, but I need to update by the ID

```
//This is the controller

import DfrModel from './dfr.model';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import config from '../../config/config';
import bodyParser = require('body-parser');
import DFRActivityModel from './DFRActivity.model';
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";

export default class DfrController {

public updateOne = async (req:Request, res:Response): Promise<any> => {
    const dfr = new DfrModel(req.body);
    console.log(req.params.id);
    try {
        const updateDFRs = await DfrModel.findByIdAndUpdate( mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),{$set:{'projectName': 'CHANGED 1234', 'projectNumber': '12345'}}); 
        //const updateDFRs = await DfrModel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{$set:{'projectName': 'CHANGED 1234', 'projectNumber': '12345'}}); //Does not work either

        if (updateDFRs === null || updateDFRs.nModified === 0) {
            return res.status(404).send({
                success: false,
                message: 'Error Saving DFR',
                data: null
              });
        }

        res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            data: dfr
          });

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({
            success: false,
            message: err.toString(),
            data: null
        });
    }
}
```

}

```
// This is the model
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const DFRSchema = Schema ({
    _id: {
        type: String,
    },
    projectName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    projectNumber: {
        type: String,
        required:false,
        trim: true
    }
};
export default mongoose.model("DFR", DFRSchema);
```

I would be expected the document record to update, to the fields I have defined.

Comment: id is `_id` `findByIdAndUpdate( { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id) }`

Comment: Yup and I can just pass in the id, I don't need 'mongoose.Types.ObjectId'

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I wanted to use the form data (which is based of the model) and update the document and get the latest document back, I did:

```
const updateDFRs = await DfrModel.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id},  req.body, {new: true});
```